# I get a Unknown Error error when a request httpClient

Tags: ionic4

I get this error:

`ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error Code: 0
Message: Http failure response for https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx: 0 Unknown Error[object Object]"`

I use this code to Ionic 4 project:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' });
return await this.http
      .get("https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx", { headers: httpHeaders })
      .toPromise();
```

The server https://xxxxxxxxxx.com is setting to : accept allow origin CORS *

In the browser, the request is 200 ok and there is the data expected

Comment: On what platform do you see the error?

Comment: web platform... PWA

Comment: What I mean is: Are you getting the error in a desktop browser like Chrome or on IOS / Android

Comment: in a desktop browser

Comment: Are you running an ad-blocker by any chance?

Comment: no, there are not any